# using resources in xaml according to localization

Tags: wpf, localization

I like pretty much of the localization model in asp.mvc. You have the resx-fallback mechanism and with some html-helper methods you can easily reference your resources in your views.

ie: `<%: Html.Resource("ApplicationTitle") %>`

I want to know if there is something similar in WPF. 
If you can use something like this on xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source=Resources.ApplicationTitle}" />
```

Also how to tell your application which resource file to use (default, en, en-us).

**Edit:**

I found how to reference resources properties directly on XAML. You can have a Language.resx file on your solution and reference it on App.xaml:

```
<SolutionName:Language x:Key="LocalizedStrings" />
```

Then just use something like this on XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
```

The only problem now is how to decide which resource to use: Language.resx or Language.en.resx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could easily do something like this writing a custom:

- attached property,
- behavior or
- markup extension

Comment: Sorry for the lack of experience on my part but I can't figure it out how to accomplish this using attached properties or behaviors. As for resource extensions, I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Sorry I meant to type **markup** extensions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx

Comment: I read the article but honestly i'm not seeing how to use the markup extensions. The article gave me an idea though. I can use a converter to decide the resx-fallback mechanism.

Comment: Yes the converter is the 4th approach. All 4 approaches come down to the same point: using code to intercept setting a value in XAML.

Comment: I just found a blog (http://shujaatsiddiqi.blogspot.com/2010/08/wpf-localization-using-resx.html) with your solution implemented. I already tried it and it worked. Thanks for your help =)